# Retain parent scrolling when interacting with an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, scroll, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

My desired use case is: My HTML page embeds a remote video (e.g. Vimeo, YouTube) using an iframe. I need scrolling to remain with my parent page at all times, but to allow click interactions with the contents of the iframe.

Default browser behaviour is for the iframe to capture scroll events when the user hovers or interacts with the contents of the iframe. Setting pointer-events:none on the iframe does not achieve the effect I need as it disables clicking in the iframe as well as disabling scrolling.

The behaviour I'm looking for is to have the iframe appear as if it were any other asset on my page (like an image). The user could choose to scroll past it if they're not interested, but if they are they can click and interact. But no matter what, a scroll or touch drag event would scroll the parent, not the iframe.

Is this possible, what with cross-domain restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the overflow inside of the iframe to none which would prevent users from scrolling inside of the iframe but allow scrolling on the main webpage. It also would allow the user to continue to interact with the iframe by clicking but prevent scrolling. Code :

```
<iframe src="iframe url" title="myIframe" style="overflow: none"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite the result I was looking for. If the user is hovering over the iframe or interacting with it, the scroll event is invisible to the parent. So whilst this does disable scrolling from being a possibility within the iframe, the parent does not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the inverse problem.  I am needing the iframe to scroll, but ui elements I have on the parent to still be clickable / hoverable.

For yours.  It's not the greatest solution, but you could place an element of the iframe on the parent with pointer event - none.  This would prevent scrolling, but would also block click in the iframe.  You could set a flag so that once the parent element was clicked once, pointer-events were set to all.  But this would require the user to click twice.  You could mitigate the ui confusion some by showing a label like "Click to interact"

Not the greatest solution I know.  If anyone knows how to be elective about which pointer events pass through I would love to know too.